# slurmd: error: Couldn't find the specified plugin name for cgroup/v2 looking at all files

Tags: centos, slurm

**I am facing issue when starting slurmd service on my compute nodes.**

× slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-10-12 04:10:25 EDT; 7s ago
Process: 5839 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd -D -s $SLURMD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 5839 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CPU: 3ms
Oct 12 04:10:25 compute1.ghpcv3.au.dk systemd[1]: Started Slurm node daemon.
Oct 12 04:10:25 compute1.ghpcv3.au.dk systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 12 04:10:25 compute1.ghpcv3.au.dk systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

#slurmd -D -vv
slurmd: debug:  Log file re-opened
slurmd: debug:  CPUs:1 Boards:1 Sockets:1 CoresPerSocket:1 ThreadsPerCore:1
slurmd: error: Couldn't find the specified plugin name for cgroup/v2 looking at all files
slurmd: error: cannot find cgroup plugin for cgroup/v2
slurmd: error: cannot create cgroup context for cgroup/v2
slurmd: error: Unable to initialize cgroup plugin
slurmd: error: slurmd initialization failed

**What I missing?**

Answer (score 1):

You may have to manually create `cgroup.conf` in your slurm config directory https://stackoverflow.com/a/65226055/5749775

I fixed this by creating a fairly simple conf:

```
# /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup.conf

CgroupAutomount=yes
# CgroupReleaseAgentDir="/etc/slurm/cgroup"

ConstrainCores=yes
ConstrainDevices=yes
# TaskAffinity=yes
ConstrainRAMSpace=yes
# ConstrainSwapSpace=yes
MaxRAMPercent=98
AllowedSwapSpace=0
AllowedRAMSpace=100
MemorySwappiness=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Slurm has support for both cgroup/v1 and v2, but support for v2 is only compiled in if the dbus development files are present. So first install `dbus-devel`

```bash
dnf install dbus-devel
```

and then run a clean Slurm build.